# Invalid manifest.json but not locally

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I made some changes to a Chrome Extension of mine, I updated the manifest.json by changing the extension's version number and, finally, I uploaded it to the Chrome Web Store.

[Here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/previeweet/ioknjbncflfoefodkjodmddcpahnhkgh) is the url.

Now if you try to install it, you'll get an "invalid manifest" error.
The problem here is that I don't either get this error with the locally unpacked version or when I upload the extesion to the Chrome Web Store.

[This](http://pastie.org/pastes/5626485/text) is the manifest.json

Comment: [Here](http://pastebin.com/vBTWe5sn) is the generated manifest from the [in-store CRX](https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx?response=redirect&x=id%3Dioknjbncflfoefodkjodmddcpahnhkgh%26uc%26lang%3Den&prod=chrome&prodversion=5.0.375.99";).

Comment: Thank you @apsillers adding "update_url" did the trick!

Comment: Good to hear that you found the answer, I'm deleting mine so you can answer with the proper one for future people.